# ZK Calendar "x more" link does not pop up a window with the x more events

Tags: zk, zk-calendar

I have a ZK calendar component with `calendars`. When I create multiple events in a day, it produces this link with "x more" where normally a pop up is shown when clicked on the link. It used to work for me but now when I click on the link nothing happens. I see this error on the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'undefined')
    at HTMLTableCellElement.onMoreClick (calendar.wpd:11:11973)
    at HTMLTableCellElement.dispatch (zk.wpd:142:116)
    at m.handle (zk.wpd:138:113)
```

Did anyone experience the same and how can I resolve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your error.

Please [turn on js-debug](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Configuration%20Reference/zk.xml/The%20client-config%20Element/The%20debug-js%20Element) in `zk.xml` and show me the error stack again. Because your current js error stack trace is from a compressed js. That is hard to identify which part of the code produces the error.

Please tell me which calendar version you use.

Do you include any javascript file to override the calendar widget?